# Log-In page - Java Swing

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, authentication

I'm having some bother with JDBC and the creation of a log in page. I have a button called btnLogIn and 2 text fields, one called UsernameField, and the other called PasswordField(which is an actual password field).

What I'm trying to achieve is, when the user enters information into the fields, the database searches the the database I have set up, then 'logs in' by displaying an appropriate welcome message or error message.

What am I doing wrong? I am very very lost. My code is below.

```
btnLogIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // creating connection and query variables
            Connection conn = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            PreparedStatement pst = null;
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://MY.DB.URL/*******"; 

            //load the driver
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                // making connection
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "*******", "*******");
                // query
                String sql = "select * from log_in where username = ? and pssword = ?";
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, UsernameField.getText());
                pst.setString(2, PasswordField.getText());
                rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);

                if(rs.next()){
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    String username = rs.getString("username");
                    System.out.println("Username : " +  username);
                    String password = rs.getString("pssword");
                    System.out.println("Password : " +  password);
                    lblLog_In.setText("Welcome.");
                } else {
                    lblLog_In.setText("ERROR: invalid log in information.");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQL Exception.");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Class not found exception.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What's not working? What you've described/posted is analagous to calling up the doctor and telling him "something's wrong" and expecting him to fix it.

Comment: Your database column is really named "pssword" or is it a typo in your query? Btw you should not do this operation in the event thread.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had put in a paragraph at the end of wht comes up, I must have forgotten. What comes up in the console is something like com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@689d11fe. There is no change to the JFrame. And pssword is correct in the DB.

Comment: Please post the complete console output

Comment: I have. Look to the above comment.

Comment: This is the only output? This would be printed if you pass a `ResultSet` to `System.out.println()`, but I don't see such a call in your code.

Comment: Just fixed it, there was a build path error which prevented changes from being acknowledged. I realised with wht you said, feuerball, as I had printed the ResultSet earlier. Thanks guys!